# MySQL: Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'

Tags: mysql

Коллеги, 
по требованию безопасников на работе, пришлось откатиться с MqSQL 5.5 на 5.1, т.к. оф поддержка со стороны RedHat есть только этой версии. Экспортированную базу с 5.5. импортировал в 5.1. Всё работает, кроме репликационного сервера. Ошибка при подключении к мастеру. Я связываю это проблему с этим (результат выполнения команды **mysql_upgrade**):

```
Repairing tables
performance_schema.cond_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_current
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_history
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_history_long
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_instance
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.file_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.file_summary_by_event_name
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.file_summary_by_instance
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.mutex_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.performance_timers
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.rwlock_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.setup_consumers
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.setup_instruments
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.setup_timers
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.threads
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
ERROR 29 (HY000) at line 349: File '/var/log/general.log' not found (Errcode: 13                                                                              )
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Пробовал делать оптимизацию и repair - не помогает. Укажите, пожалуйста, путь к решению проблемы. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` - фича, появившаяся в 5.5, в 5.1 она не работает. Сервер версии 5.5 в рамках этой фичи создал таблицы для ведения статистики производительности, а 5.1 не понимает, что с ними делать. `REPAIR` не поможет - ничего не "сломано" и "чинить" нечего.

Идеальный вариант - на 5.5 сдампить все нужные Вам базы, удалить полностью MySQL сервер со всеми его данными, поставить чистый 5.1 и восстановить базы из дампов. Не забудьте про пользователей mysql.

Comment: 5.5 полностью удалил, 5.1 с нуля поставил. Базы-то сдампил с 5.5 и импортнул в 5.1. Сейчас уже не откатиться назад, т.к. базы импортированы и в них уже есть изменения.

Comment: То есть Вы проделали всё это сразу на продакшене, без проверки в тестовом окружении?

Comment: К сожалению да. Не предполагал что могут быть проблемы

Comment: Даунгрейд мажорной `(a.x -> a.y)` версии - всегда потенциально опасная ситуация. Насколько много данных в базе, какой объем общего дампа всего-всего?

Comment: 10 баз. Общий объём 80 Мб. С момента импорта баз на 5.1 в ней уже есть изменения, которые будет достаточно проблематично восстановить.

Comment: Дампить базы каждую вручную, чистить MySQL 5.1 и потом каждую имортировать?

Comment: А, так это совсем немного. Я боялся, что сотни гигабайт. Поднимите себе тестовое окружение с 5.1, сдампите всё что сейчас есть, разверните в тестовом окружении и экспериментируйте там (и всегда так делайте!). Я бы начал с попытки просто взять и дропнуть базу `performance_schema`. Кстати, мы тут с Вами про performance_schema говорим, а проблема-то у Вас в репликации? Дополните вопрос описанием того, как именно она "не работает". Может быть эти две проблемы и не связаны вовсе.

Comment: удалил базу, сделал повторный дамп, импортнул на реплику, стартанул - всё ок. Спасибо!